# Select columns that match "A1" and "A2" but not "AA1"

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using jQuery DataTables to Export to Excel.  Here is data structure it creates.

```
<row r="1">
  <c r="A1">....</c>
  <c r="B1">....</c>
  <c r="C1">....</c>
  ...
  ...
  <c r="AA1">....</c>
  <c r="AB1">....</c>
</row>
<row r="2">
  <c r="A2">....</c>
  <c r="B2">....</c>
  <c r="C2">....</c>
  ...
  ...
  <c r="AA2">....</c>
  <c r="AB2">....</c>
</row>
```

Here is the selector I've got

```
$('row c[r^="A"]', sheet).each(function () {
```

This correctly selects "A1", "A2",...."A15".   But unfortunately it also selects everything after "Z".. which is "AA1","AB1","AA2", etc...

Because the ^ selector says "anything that starts with 'A'".  But to function as desired, it seems I need some way of selecting "Starts with [letter], and followed by a number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the .filter() method from jquery.

```
$('row c[r^="A"]', sheet).filter(function() {
  console.log(this.className);
  //if you "return true;" here the element will be kept in the result
  // do checks like if (this.className.contains ...) or whatever you need. 
  // if you "return false;" it won't be kept
}).each(function() {
  //here will only be the elements where you returned true on the filter operation
})
```

Comment: @adam, consider accepting the answer if it helped you out.